Find last occurrence with UNIQUE
There is a vector of numbers:
y = [
2013;
2013;
2013;
2014;
2014;
2015;
2016]

Scilab function unique creates the vector km with indexes of the first occuring unique number in y:
[U, km, ku, nb] = unique(y)

km is:
1
4
6
7

I need a index vector of the last occurrence of the unique numbers like:
3
5
6
7

How can I achieve this?

You can just apply unique to y($:-1:1) and then let
km=n-km+1 where n is the size of y
